# Sequelize get N:M association from foreign key

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, rest, sequelize.js

I have a schema where I have an Asset which has many threats and each threat has many countermeasures. What I want to do is given the id of an asset to get the list of the threats, and the list countermeasures for each threat, of that asset. How can I achieve that?

I don't think my code will provide any help, but here you go anyway:

```
Asset.belongsToMany(Threat, { through: 'asset-threat' });
Threat.belongsToMany(Asset, { through: 'asset-threat' });

Countermeasure.belongsToMany(Threat, { through: 'countermeasure-threat' });
Threat.belongsToMany(Countermeasure, { through: 'countermeasure-threat' });
```

All the association stuff are here. I let sequelize handle everything that has to do with keys foreiggn and not.

#### Edit

Something I tried to do that doesnt work but explains really well what I want to achieve is the following:

```
const asset = await Asset.findOne({ where: { id } });

return await asset.getThreats({
    include: Countermeasure
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you should indicate `include` option values as an array:

```
return await asset.getThreats({
    include: [Countermeasure]
});
```

Comment: ... seriously ... That was it... I asked.. this thing... Anyway, thank you kind sir!